# Set modification time in matlab

Tags: file, matlab, octave

I can get modification time in matlab by:

```
>> f = dir('my_filename.dat');
>> f.date
```

But how can I change it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is can be done using Java&Matlab:

```
import java.io.File java.text.SimpleDateFormat
f = File('my_filename.dat');
sdf = SimpleDateFormat('HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy');
newDate = sdf.parse('12:34 10/12/2010');
f.setLastModified(newDate.getTime);
```

Answer (score 4):

To set the date to the current date you can write something to the file:

```
fid = fopen('my_filename.dat', 'r+');
byte = fread(fid, 1);
fseek(fid, 0, 'bof');
fwrite(fid, byte);
fclose(fid);
```

Here, I read a single byte from the beginning of the file, and I write it back.

If you want to set it to something else, you can do it with a system call. On linux you can use `touch` for that:

```
system('touch -d "2012-10-01" my_filename.dat');
```

Similar command exists for windows (`Touch`) in the [Win32 Console ToolBox 1.0](http://www.stevemiller.net/apps/)

Comment: Or just set the windows system clock to your desired date, make a null change to the file, and change the clock back :)

Answer (score 1):

Building on the Java solution:

```
function setFileDate(fn,date)
% date needs to be UTC I think

java.io.File(fn).setLastModified(etime(datevec(date),[1970 1 1 0 0 0])*1000);
```

Or

```
function updateFileDate(fn)
java.io.File(fn).setLastModified(java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis)
```