# MATLAB won't delete temporary images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filehandle

I have an image analysis program in MATLAB that grabs images from a hardware frame grabber. It saves them to a temporary folder (`%TEMP%\yymmdd-hhmmss\` in Windows), analyses them, then attempts to delete them. But the delete operation always fails with **"The file is in use by another process"**. Evidently MATLAB still has them open somehow.

I can't find any open handles using `fopen('all')`. I'm using `imread` to read the images - does it still retain an open handle somewhere? And if so, how can I close it?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this error. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces what you're experiencing.

Comment: @excaza Thanks! In the process of generating a MCVE, I did a bit more digging and found the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a little digging into this. It turned out that the image file was being locked by a MATLAB function [GetFileTime](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24671-filetime/content/GetFileTime.m), which I was using to set the image's modification time after grabbing. I'm not sure why it locks the file, but I found a [different method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030143/set-modification-time-in-matlab) to set the file time which doesn't result in the file being locked.

(Thanks to @excaza for making me look into this better. It was the end of the day, and I couldn't work it out, so I just posted here. Very lazy of me!)

Answer (score 0):

If `fclose('all')` or `pack` don't work for you, be sure that no other programs (i.e. anti-virus) are trying to scan the temp directory.  For my applications, creating a subfolder in my working directory has avoided access problems.